# ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I notice my VBA script doesn't work when there's an autofilter already on. Any idea why this is?

```
    wbk.Activate
    Set Criteria = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4))

    wb.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 'remove autofilter, but it crashes on this line

    Selection.AutoFilter

    Range("$A$1:$BM$204").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Criteria.Value

    rng.Copy

    Range("$BC$2:$BE$204").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial
```

Many thanks

Comment: What error are you getting on the line it crashes on?

Comment: A runtime error: ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed

Answer (score 67):

AutoFilterMode will be True if engaged, regardless of whether there is actually a filter applied to a specific column or not.  When this happens, `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` will still run, throwing an error (because there is no actual filtering).

I had the same issue and got it working with

```
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
```

This seems to prevent ShowAllData from running when there is no actual filter applied but with AutoFilterMode turned on.

The second catch `Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode` should catch advanced filters

Comment: There is a logical problem:  **(A and B) or B == B**, therefore your solution is equivalent to  .  .  .  .  .                
    `If  ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ...`

Answer (score 42):

The simple way to avoid this is not to use the worksheet method ShowAllData

Autofilter has the same ShowAllData method which doesn't throw an error when the filter is enabled but no filter is set

`If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData`

Comment: Aren't `Autofilter` and `ShowAllData` different methods? While `Autofilter` **removes** filter, `ShowAllData` only **clears** it.

Comment: The OP is referring to Worksheet.ShowAllData giving an error when the filter is on but no criteria is selected and my answer is to use Worksheet.Autofilter.ShowAllData which doesn't cause an error when no filter criteria is selected. -   It's ShowAllData that's the same method,

Comment: I didn't know that difference and actually that also solved my current problem after your better explanation Steven, thanks a lot!

Comment: This solved my issue. I was doing the logical test mentioned in the higher-ranked answer and still encountering OP's error.

Comment: Just check for the FilterMode condition. That will solve the problem (at least it did in Excel 2016). The AutoFilterMode property returns TRUE when the Auto Filter Mode is on, irrespective of whether filter criteria were applied. Consequently, then no criteria are applied, the ShowAllData method will display an error.

Comment: You misunderstood the op question

Answer (score 12):

The error `ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed` usually occurs when you try to remove an applied filter when there is not one applied.

I am not certain if you are trying to remove the whole `AutoFilter`, or just remove any applied filter, but there are different approaches for each.

To remove an applied filter but leave `AutoFilter` on:

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
```

The rationale behind the above code is to test that there is an `AutoFilter` or whether a filter has been applied (this will also remove advanced filters).

To completely remove the `AutoFilter`:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

In the above case, you are simply disabling the `AutoFilter` completely.

Comment: I have updated my code to the following:
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.FilterMode = False I want to completely remove the filters. However, I now notice the paste method also pastes into the first (invisible?) three cells. I'm not able to understand this.

Comment: @KrisVandenBergh I'm glad the initial problem is solved :)  If there is another problem with your `PasteSpecial` method it might be worth raising a new question for it as this one was to figure out the error with the `AutoFilter`.

Comment: @KrisVandenBergh As your original problem has been solved, could you mark this question as answered?  Thanks

Comment: @KrisVandenBergh can you please approve this question as answered please. It still seems unanswered.

Comment: Btw @MartinParkin, I'm facing with almost same issue but even `If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode` `Then`
    `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData`
`End If` doesn't help me. And interestingly sometimes I get this error , sometimes not I don't know why that's happening. Any ideas?

Comment: @StevenMartin 's answer below solved my problem. Fyi

Answer (score 5):

I have just experienced the same problem. After some trial-and-error I discovered that *if the selection was to the right of my filter area AND the number of shown records was zero, ShowAllData would fail*.

A little more context is probably relevant. I have a number of sheets, each with a filter. I would like to set up some standard filters on all sheets, therefore I use some VBA like this

```
Sheets("Server").Select
col = Range("1:1").Find("In Selected SLA").Column
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Srv").Range.AutoFilter Field:=col, Criteria1:="TRUE"
```

This code will adjust the filter on the column with heading "In Selected SLA", and leave all other filters unchanged. This has the unfortunate side effect that I can create a filter that shows zero records. This is not possible using the UI alone.

To avoid that situation, I would like to reset all filters before I apply the filtering above. My reset code looked like this

```
Sheets("Server").Select
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

Note how I did not move the selected cell. If the selection was to the right, it would not remove filters, thus letting the filter code build a zero-row filter. The second time the code is run (on a zero-row filter) ShowAllData will fail.

The workaround is simple: Move the selection inside the filter columns before calling ShowAllData

```
Application.Goto (Sheets("Server").Range("A1"))
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

This was on Excel version 14.0.7128.5000 (32-bit) = Office 2010

Comment: The Selection is only relevant, when you works with ListObjects - those can be filtered separately, more than one area in a single sheet.
Normal (single) sheet Filter can be accessable simply through Worksheet object.

Answer (score 2):

This will work. Define this, then call it from when you need it. (Good for button logic if you are making a clear button):

```
Sub ResetFilters()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also the same problem. I think the reason are,

1) When my activecell is within the table, "ActiveSheet.ShowAllData" can be work.
2) When my activecell not within the table, 
"ActiveSheet.ShowAllData" cannot work.Using this code, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Srv").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1 can clear the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code below. Once turns it off, releases the filter. Second time turns it back on without filters.

Not very elegant, but served my purpose.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable").Range.AutoFilter

'then call it again?
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTable").Range.AutoFilter
```