# Removing Filters for Each Pivot Table in a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort through each table within each worksheet in an active workbook and reset all the filters.

Note that each table is a pivot table.

```
Sub ResetFilters()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim listObj  As ListObjects

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each listObj In ws
            With ActiveSheet.listObj.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        End With
        Next listObj
    Next ws
    End Sub
```

Error received: "Object doesn't suppor this property or method" on Line 7.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the error messages you're receiving.

Comment: Edited per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean clear filters and remove sorting, you can use:

```
Sub ResetFilters()
    Dim ws                    As Worksheet
    Dim wb                    As Workbook
    Dim listObj               As ListObject

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each listObj In ws.ListObjects
            If listObj.ShowHeaders Then
                listObj.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                listObj.Sort.SortFields.Clear
            End If
        Next listObj
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: How would this change if it were to remove sorting, instead?

Comment: Both forms returned an error. "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: I've updated the code to cope with tables with no header row.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, and it keeps occurring on the section of: listObj.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

I've tried multiple methods of calling the list object, some will run fine (without error), but not actually clear or remove sorting.

Comment: Does this code change if the tables are pivot tables?

Comment: Yes - pivot tables are completely different. Do you need pivot tables as well as, or instead of, Tables?

Comment: The data I'm using is all in tables, but for some reason the code above wasn't pulling in. I have the pivot tables set to clear in another piece of code.

Comment: Can you post a workbook somewhere? Note that clearing the sort fields won't actually change the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for with a small change to the previous answer.  Just use the ShowAutoFilter property instead of ShowHeaders.  ShowAutoFilter is the property that references the these things: [Screencap of AutoFilter Dropdown Box in Excel Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPfgr.png)

(I would have just commented on the other answer, but I need 50 "reputation" -_- )

Answer (score 0):

**7-line solution**
This will show all data without removing the filter, and won't fail on unfiltered sheets.

```
Sub RemoveFilters()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
Next ws
End Sub
```

The poster's VBA might have failed on encountering an unfiltered sheet.

To remove each filter entirely, just replace lines 4+5 with `Cells.AutoFilter`.