# Create an IF statement to check and remove the advanced filter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet "Results" that will have an advanced filter applied to it. I have a macro that copies the results from one sheet (Function Test Procedure) to another (Results) and another macro then applies an advanced filter to determine if there are any failures. I have the copy script working properly and the filter works as well (for the most part). The issue I am running into is the act of attempting to paste results into a named range that has a(n) (advanced) filter applied to it. When it fails, it will result in unexpected formatting and it will attempt to paste the results below and "alter" the later steps of pasting select cells from Results to another worksheet (Failure Report) which populates any values that have a "Failure".  I have tried adding:

```
Sheets("Results").ShowAllData
```

or

```
If AdvancedFilter = Active Then
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If
```

and neither work.  I have tried adding them before and after the loop, but I believe I am using the wrong keywords.  This is the full script I am using to copy the sections from Function Test Procedure to Results.

```
Sub Copy_Filtered_Sections()

 Dim Section As Long, NextRow As Long
 Dim FATPMetiPath As String, FATPMetiFolderPath As String
 Dim rng As Range
 Sheets("Results").Activate

 Sheets("Results").Range("Results").ClearContents
 For Section = 1 To 13 '32

    NextRow = Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next empty row

    Sheets("Function Test Procedure").Select

    Range("FTPSec" & Section).Columns("A:H").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Results").Range("A" & NextRow)

 Next Section

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try any of these solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761027/excel-2013-vba-clear-all-filters-macro

Comment: @Ralph - Thank you for sending me the link.  It works exactly as intended.