# removing the autofilter with command button

Tags: vba, excel

I have an userform designed with 3 listbox and 2 Buttons.

by selecting the item in the listbox and the button1, i get the filetred result of sheet.

With the command button2, i would like to remove the filter used and get back to the original sheet.

I used the below code,

```
Private Sub CBExit_Click()
Sheets("Data").ShowAllData
Unload Me
 End Sub
```

with this everytime i get an error message that

> showalldata method of worksheet class failed

How can I overcome this error ?

I wanted to clear the filter result and get back to the original sheet with the command button.

any lead would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all filters then try `Cells.AutoFilter`

Comment: I tried this as well, and it dint work

Comment: `.ShowAllData` method sets the selection of an AutoFilter to "all", whereas `.AutoFilter` removes the filter alltogether.

Comment: I would like to use .showalldata, while I just like to clear my filter result.

Comment: But in the above link also, i was not able to find a solution for my  problem

Comment: is there anyother way to clear the filetr result ?

Comment: Try This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761027/excel-2013-vba-clear-all-filters-macro