# Run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method for filter removal

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple books with multiple sheets that I'm copying data from. Sometimes filters are applied and someone forgets to remove it. It gets all wonky if I try to copy filtered data so I'm trying to remove filters in it is filtered.

```
With WB2
    For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
        With .Sheets(i)
            If .AutoFilterMode Then
                .Cells.AutoFilter
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

I'm getting a 438 error with "If .AutoFilterMode Then" highlighted.

I've used this block of code on other books before it and it passes and gets stuck on this one.

Comment: Are you sure the `.Sheets(i)` in question is a `Worksheet` and not another sheet type?

Comment: For Each ws In WB2.Worksheets
        ws.Cells.AutoFilter
    Next

is giving 1004 error saying autofilter method of range class failed even though the same works on other books.

Comment: Test `If .AutoFilterMode` and then maybe use `.Autofiler.ShowAllData`? Or however you prefer to clear the filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761027/excel-2013-vba-clear-all-filters-macro