# How to clear filters in Excel using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, filter, xlwings

My team are xlwings in Sypder (Python) to convert Excel tables into CSV format. When a table is filtered however, this alters the CSV output. Is there an xlwings command which can clear the filter from the active Excel sheet?

A similar command in VBA would be (from [Excel 2013 VBA Clear All Filters macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761027/excel-2013-vba-clear-all-filters-macro)):

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

`wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilterMode = False`
Will remove the filter from the sheet, if you want to just clear the filter showing all the data without removing it you can use:
`wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilter.ShowAllData()`

Answer (score 4):

We found a way to disable filters using...

```
if wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilterMode == True:
      wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: As @avkch suggests in his anwer, this will remove the filter altogether. See the answer by Mike.

Answer (score 2):

This will clear the filters if any are active:

```
if wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilterMode:
    wb.sheets[sheetname].api.AutoFilter.ShowAllData()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: <unknown>.AutoFilterMode. Did you mean: 'AutoFilter'?` . This seems to work though with `if ...AutoFilter:`.