# Auto sorting and filtering macro worked in Excel 2010 but no longer in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that filters and sorts service desk tickets into different color coded categories and severity levels. It used to work in Excel 2010 but I'm trying to run it in Excel 2016 and it's throwing 2 errors.

The first is

> "Run-time error 91 - Object variable or With block variable not set"

It seems to be stuck on this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

and the second error is

> "Run-time error '1004' - The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank"

That error is pointing to .Apply in the code below.

I'm not familiar with VBA code at all, so I'm quite stuck, I've inherited the code from a colleague. The code snippet throwing the errors are below.

```
Range("A1:S1").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("V3").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("V1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Added the code that quantifies variable SheetName1

```
'Insert Active.Worksheetname to A300. This is required to allow the filters to function later on, as the worksheet name varies according to the exported CSV file name
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=288
Range("A300").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=MID(CELL(""filename"",R[-299]C),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-299]C),1)+1,255)"
Dim SheetName1
SheetName1 = Trim(Range("A300").Value)
```

Any help to get this code working would be much appreciated.

I've now edited that section to be as follows:

```
    Range("A1:S1").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("V3").Select

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName1)
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear

        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("V1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With .AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```

Error 1004 still being thrown and highlighted ".Apply"

I'm really not a programmer or understand code at all really, so excuse the lack of comprehension of your answers.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • The variable `SheetName1` is not set and therefore it is `Nothing`. • Also check if you really meant to use `ActiveWorkbook` which is the workbook that has the focus (is on top) because you probably wanted to use `ThisWorkbook` which is the workbook this code is running in.

Comment: The range in `Key:=  Range("V1")` needs to be fully qualified with a sheet name like `Key:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).Range("V1")`

Comment: [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761027/excel-2013-vba-clear-all-filters-macro)

Comment: Change: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add` for `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2`

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. Edited original post, I understand the concepts of removing .Select and defining variables, just not sure how to write the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic code example, use `With` statements to properly qualify your sheet, remove and don't use `Select`, comments are provided to clarify.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName1) 'If `SHeetName1` is the actual sheet name it must be in parentheses ""
    .AutoFilterMode = False 'Remove filters
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear 'Will fail if the previous filter was not removed 

    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("V1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With .AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```