# Excel VBA - ShowAllData method of Worksheet Class failed

Tags: vba, excel, filter, named-ranges

I have automated a proper record input into the table that I use as a database, and when the table is filtered the input don't work.

So I have code this to unfilter DataBase before every record input.

```
Public Sub UnFilter_DB()
Dim ActiveS As String, CurrScreenUpdate As Boolean

CurrScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveS = ActiveSheet.Name

    Sheets("DB").Activate
    Sheets("DB").Range("A1").Activate
    Sheets("DB").ShowAllData
    DoEvents
    Sheets(ActiveS).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = CurrScreenUpdate
End Sub
```

But now, it stays stuck on `Sheets("DB").ShowAllData` saying :

> ShowAllData method of Worksheet Class failed

because the table is already unfiltered...

And I don't know if it is better to **use an error handler** like `On Error Resume Next` or how to **detect if there is a filter or none**.

Any pointers would be welcome!

Comment: You're not doing this in a loop or anything so no difference IMHO. I would just add `On Error Resume Next` before `ShowAllData` and then `On Error Goto 0` after `ShowAllData`

Comment: @AnalystCave.com : I tried that but still sometimes an error still show up... See answer if you are interested!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20581889/935614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **working solution** I went with :

```
Public Sub UnFilter_DB()
Dim ActiveS As String, CurrScreenUpdate As Boolean

CurrScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveS = ActiveSheet.Name

    Sheets("DB").Activate
    Sheets("DB").Range("A1").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets("DB").FilterMode = True Then Sheets("DB").ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    DoEvents
    Sheets(ActiveS).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = CurrScreenUpdate
End Sub
```

---

And a **more efficient version** I wrote to be reusable easily with Named Ranges :

How to use it :

```
Private Sub TEST_UnFilter_Table()
    Dim tB As Workbook, _
        Sh As Worksheet

    Set tB = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sh = tB.Sheets("DB")

    Call UnFilter_Table(Sh, "Db_Val")
End Sub
```

And the **proper function** with optimisation (if you have big tables) :

```
Public Function UnFilter_Table(ByRef SheetWithTable As Worksheet, ByVal RangeName As String) As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrHdlr
    Dim aWB As Workbook, _
        ActiveSH As Worksheet, _
        ScreenUpdateState As Boolean, _
        StatusBarState As Boolean, _
        CalcState As XlCalculation, _
        EventsState As Boolean, _
        DisplayPageBreakState As Boolean

    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ActiveSH = aWB.ActiveSheet

    DisplayPageBreakState = ActiveSH.DisplayPageBreaks
    ActiveSH.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    With Application
        ScreenUpdateState = .ScreenUpdating
        StatusBarState = .DisplayStatusBar
        CalcState = .Calculation
        EventsState = .EnableEvents

        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayStatusBar = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With


    SheetWithTable.Activate
    SheetWithTable.Range(RangeName).Cells(1, 1).Activate
On Error GoTo 0

On Error Resume Next
    If SheetWithTable.FilterMode Then SheetWithTable.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0

On Error GoTo ErrHdlr
    DoEvents
    ActiveSH.Activate
    ActiveSH.DisplayPageBreaks = DisplayPageBreakState

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdateState
        .DisplayStatusBar = StatusBarState
        .Calculation = CalcState
        .EnableEvents = EventsState
    End With

    UnFilter_Table = True
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Function
ErrHdlr:
UnFilter_Table = False
Debug.Print "Error in unfiltering sheet " & SheetWithTable.Name & " !" & vbCrLf & _
            "Error n° " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
            Err.Description
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Worksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` instead of `Worksheet.ShowAllData` it will not throw the error when nothing is filtered.

This assumes that `Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = True` because otherwise you will get an error about `AutoFilter` not being an object.

```
Public Sub UnFilter_DB()
Dim ActiveS As String, CurrScreenUpdate As Boolean

CurrScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveS = ActiveSheet.Name

    Sheets("DB").Activate
    Sheets("DB").Range("A1").Activate
    Sheets("DB").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    DoEvents
    Sheets(ActiveS).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = CurrScreenUpdate
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! I combine `On Error Resume Next`, test on `AutoFilterMode` and you correction with `AutoFilter` and now it runs everytime without any problem! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
With ActiveSheet
     If .AutoFilterMode = False Then .Cells(1, 1).AutoFilter
     For Each f In .AutoFilter.Filters
          If f.On Then .ShowAllData: Exit For
Next
```