# Add filter bars to a table

Tags: vba, excel

If I have multiple tables in a single spreadsheet and both of them have filter bars, how can I check if one of them has filter bars and, if not, give it filter bars?

I tried a **"If Not .AutoFilter Then"** statement, but it's always false.

So this code always works:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(2).HeaderRowRange
    If Not .AutoFilter Then
        .AutoFilter
    End If
End With
```

Keep in mind .AutoFilterMode, .FilterMode and .ShowAllData seem to work on whole sheets and not on tables.

[image]

Comment: It's `.FilterMode` you are looking for! ;) See this for more detailed code on how to check before using `ShowAllData` on a specific table http://stackoverflow.com/a/39744623/4628637