# Run-time error '1004' ShowAllData method of Worksheets class failed

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Iam getting confused. Can someone try to explain this for me.
Below is a part of recorded macro im using. Sometimes it runs with no error while 10 minutes later ill get the error message in the Title field, and it stops at the LAST ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

It so unlogical for mer but probably there is an explanation to this.
Im always in the same sheet when activating the macro..

```
Sheets("DB2 Totbel").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Sheets("DB2 Giva").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Sheets("TS4LAGER").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Sheets("PIX").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PIX").ListObjects("Table_Query_from_DB2W").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    Sheets("OFO data").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Sheets("Arbetsyta").Select
    **ActiveSheet.ShowAllData**
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226045/showalldata-method-of-worksheet-class-failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of the state of `FilterMode`.

Personally, I made this (user won't see anything happening) to cancel filters on a sheet :

```
Public Sub UnFilter_Tables_On_Sheet(Sheet_Name As String)
Dim ActiveS As String, CurrScreenUpdate As Boolean

CurrScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveS = ActiveSheet.Name

    Sheets(Sheet_Name).Activate
    Sheets(Sheet_Name).Range("A1").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    If Sheets(Sheet_Name).FilterMode = True Then Sheets(Sheet_Name).ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    DoEvents
    Sheets(ActiveS).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = CurrScreenUpdate
End Sub
```

You can simply use it like this : `Call UnFilter_Tables_On_Sheet("Sheet1")`

Comment: Perfect..thanks, this will reduce my earlier code a lot, as  i now activated a filter just to be able to clear it later with above (my previous recorded code). Perfect with a public to call..

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Constants.MySheetName).Select
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(Constants.MyTblName).HeaderRowRange.Select

On Error Resume Next

ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

On Error GoTo 0
```

By using the HeaderRowRange value the table is selected without explicit row and col.