# Keep getting Error when I try to clear all filters

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro in my Excel sheet and sometimes it will work other times it throws up and error.

I cannot work it out as I thought I had covered all the possible options for auto filters and if someone adds a manual filter (it is a shared spreadsheet)

Please help.

```
Sub Clear_All_Filters()
'
' Clear_All_Filters Macro
' Clear Filters
'
    Worksheets("Weekly Review Meeting").Activate
    If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Or ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: What error? What message do you get? Show us.

Comment: See [ShowAllData method failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226045/showalldata-method-of-worksheet-class-failed)

Comment: Note that the `Or` conditions make the `And` part useless.

Comment: Run-Time error '1004'  is what I get.

Comment: Unfortunately even after reading the link trincot supplied I still cannot get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the following:

Sub Clear_All_Filters()
'
' Clear_All_Filters Macro
' Clear Filters
'
    Worksheets("Weekly Review Meeting").Activate

```
Range("B2").Select

    On Error Resume Next
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End If

On Error Resume Next
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End If

On Error Resume Next
If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End If


Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: It might be a round about way but it works so I am happy for the time being. I will try to understand it better some other time. Thanks for the help.