# Clear Filters with workbook close

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a function to clear any filters on the workbook (all sheets) upon close.. I have this sub already, Can someone help me script it to include the filter clear?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim sht As Worksheet, csheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set csheet = ActiveSheet
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If sht.Visible Then
    sht.Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
  End If
Next sht
csheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197246.aspx), or an [SO example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226045/showalldata-method-of-worksheet-class-failed)

Comment: Do you want to *remove* the filter or just remove any criteria set on the filter?

Comment: remove any criteria that may be set

Comment: I like this idea, but I don't know how to put it into the code and perform it on all sheets                                                                                                                       `On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0`