# AutoFilter.ShowAllData "Object Required" Error?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm attempting to select all in the AutoFilter and am using ShowAllData, it works however each time it gives an error "Object Required"?

```
Sub FilterAll()

Worksheets("Report").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

End Sub
```

This doesn't work either:

```
Sub ShowAll()

Worksheets("Report").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

With that I get an error 1004: ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed.

I am setting the filter first with a subroutine:

```
Sub Show1B()

Worksheets("Report").Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter _
    Field:=4, _
    Criteria1:="1B"

End Sub
```

And then want to "Select All" (so to speak) with the filter with the FilterAll Subroutine

Comment: The `.ShowAllData` method is for the `Worksheet` object and does not apply to a range (much less a single row of four cells). So your code should be `Worksheets("Report").ShowAllData`.

Comment: Thanks PeterT, I already tried that and it doesn't work - I get a Runtime Error 1004: ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed

Comment: Then it's probable that the worksheet is not currently filtered. You'll have to check for that condition. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20581889/4717755)

Comment: Hi PeterT, I'm looking at the filter.  It's definitely there.

Comment: Hi PeterT, I just added an If statement to check for the AutoFilterMode and it is not detecting it even though it's clearly there.  I actually set the AutoFilter with another subroutine and then want to use this subroutine to show all of the criteria.

Comment: @PeterT is right. Besides, there is only so much that can go wrong.  Wrong sheet name?  wrong workbook?  not filtered?  When you say the second example  "doesn't work either" what is the issue on that one?

Comment: Did you try some of the solutions mentioned in the SO link I provided?

Comment: Yes, PeterT and I received the same error.

Comment: Hi Ashlee, sheet name is correct workbook is correct.  I updated the answer to show the subroutine I am using to apply the filter in the first place, if that's helpful.  When I test for AutoFilterMode with an If statement it is not detecting it even though I see it and set it with that other subroutine.

Comment: If you received the same error on this line : `Worksheets("Report").ShowAllData` then that means you will receive the same error on this line: `MsgBox Worksheets("Report").Name`. Could you test that?

Comment: Hi Ashlee, I did not receive the error with the MsgBox line.  It create a MsgBox with "Report" in it

Comment: And you have an autofilter currently showing on worksheet "Report"?

Comment: Thank you each for your help but I think I figured it out - the original filter was not set programatically but manually.  I took the filter off and then ran the subroutine that created the filter and it is now working?!  Is a filter set up manually NOT an autofilter?  I find this very strange.

Comment: Yes, the autofitler was definitely showing but it was created manually before I started testing the subroutines that selected for the criteria.

Comment: If either of you want to put some sort of answer to the effect of asking me whether or not I established the filter with the VBA or manually I will accept it as correct as a thanks for all the help.

Comment: It would have to be setup in the same way.  You can confirm by recording a macro while you turn autofilter on and then clear it, and then check out the code that Excel generates,.  Anyhow good luck

Comment: I'm adding this comment for anyone else who was having similar difficulty: It appeared that ShowAllData was acting really buggy and inconsistent. In order for ShowAllData to work the active/selected cell at the moment it is executed must be WITHIN the filtered range. If you click outside of the filtered range and select another cell IT WILL NOT WORK, so it's important in the VBA to select a cell within the filtered range before executing the ShowAllData statement.

Comment: I am having the same problem now, lol. Thank you, will check out your workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Your first sub attempts to set the autofilter, then tries to get the object it returns to call showalldata. However, AutoFilter doesn't return an object. It's just a method that sets the autofilter.

The second sub, using the worksheets' ShowAllData method, is the correct way to do what you're asking, however .ShowAllData only works when the range is currently being filtered, once it's run once, it will give the 1004: ShowAllData method of Worksheet class failed. error.

To get around that, you can put on error resume next in your ShowAll function, or always ensure the filter is set before calling it.

If you call ShowAll immediately after Show1B, it should successfully clear the filtering without an error, however if you were to call ShowAll again before filtering the data again, it will give you the error you received.

Also, because these subs act on "Worksheets" as their main object, they will act on the currently active workbook.

So if you were to call Show1B, activate a different workbook, and then call ShowAll, it would be acting on two different workbooks, and give you either the "ShowAllData method failed", if the range is unfiltered or isn't currently hiding anything, or "Subscript out of range", if there was no "Report" sheet on the currently active workbook.

You can get around that by either ensuring the correct workbook is active before running each sub.

```
Sub MainProgram()
    Workbooks("Main Workbook.xlsx").Activate
    Call Show1B
    ' Other code
    Workbooks("Main Workbook.xlsx").Activate
    Call ShowAllData
End Sub
```

calling the workbook specifically within the sub, if it will always be the same. (ThisWorkbook is a shortcut for the workbook the macro actually resides in)

```
Sub ShowAllData()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").ShowAllData
End Sub
```

or alternately, if it's acting on another workbook, though this will fail if the workbook isn't currently open.

```
Sub ShowAllData()
    Workbooks("Main Workbook.xlsx").Worksheets("Report").ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Or setting the workbook or worksheet you're using to an object and passing it in when you call it.

```
' Also modify Show1B the same way
Sub ShowAll(ws as Worksheet)
    ws.ShowAllData
End Sub

Sub MainProgram()
    Dim myWs As Worksheet, myWb as Workbook
    Set myWb = ActiveWorkbook ' Or ThisWorkbook, or Workbooks("Name")
    Set myWs = myWb.Worksheets("Report")
    ' ...
    Show1B myWs
    ' ...
    ShowAll myWs
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm marking this as correct, but if you have a moment to add this info I'd appreciate it:  I figured out what was causing all my issues yesterday, which continued even after I left this thread.  It appeared that ShowAllData was acting really buggy and inconsistent.  In order for ShowAllData to work the active/selected cell at the moment it is executed must be WITHIN the filtered range.  If you click outside of the filtered range and select another cell IT WILL NOT WORK, so it's important in the VBA to select a cell within the filtered range before executing the ShowAllData statement.

Comment: I tried selecting cells out of the filtered range, and activating a different worksheet, but I only got the error you found by activating a different workbook entirely. I added information for how to detect/get around that.