# Function to Clear filters error - ShowAllData failed

Tags: vba, excel

Good Afternoon,

I have written a function that is passed an array of worksheets and is supposed to clear all filters on each worksheet.  Here is the function:

```
Function Clearwsfilters(sheets() As Object)

    For i = LBound(sheets) To UBound(sheets)
        With sheets(i)
            If .AutoFilterMode Then
                If .FilterMode Then
                    Debug.Print "Clearing Filters on Sheet: "; i
          ------>   .ShowAllData
                End If
            ElseIf .FilterMode Then
                Debug.Print "Clearing Filters on Sheet: "; i
                .ShowAllData
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Function
```

When I run it, it's getting stuck on line which I've indicated with an arrow.  This function is being passed 6 worksheets with identical names, stored in an object array.  I can provide more details about this array if necessary.

Thanks for taking a look at this

Comment: Probably is breaking because there's no applied filter, what happens if you set an `On Error Resume Next` prior to `.ShowAllData` ? Also, why do you have the same execution in the `If` and `Else If` ? I don't think you need to check if there's a filter, just clear if there's any, if not, just skip it.

Comment: If a sheet has an autofilter but no filter applied it successfully exits the loop.  The function is failing on a sheet that has a filter applied.

According to another forum I looked at, advanced filters on spreadsheets set .FilterMode to True, while .AutoFilterMode remains False.  The Else If statement is meant to catch that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ShowAllData method of worksheet class failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226045/showalldata-method-of-worksheet-class-failed)

Comment: I posted this as a separate question because I thought maybe the error came from  passing an array of worksheets into this function, instead of just manipulating a single sheet.

Comment: Instead of using `Worksheet.ShowAllData` use `Worksheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData` (Steven Martin's answer).