# Implementing a 'tag'-like filter for a column in an Excel table?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I have a column in an excel table that may contain values such as:

- 5
- 7,1,8
- 3,5
- ALL

I want to implement a macro that can filter for these values, such that if I filter for "5", the first and third results come up. Also, I included the ALL in the list because there may be text tags added in the future. Here's what I have so far, but it gets inconsistent results:

```
Sub ContainsFilter()
    Dim strName As String
    strName = InputBox("What would you like to search for?")
    If strName = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Else
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*" & strName & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of inconsistent results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ContainsFilter()
    Dim InputReturn As Variant
    InputReturn = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="What would you like to search for?", Title:="Filter Field 7", Type:=2) ' type 2 = string
    
    If VarType(InputReturn) = vbBoolean And InputReturn = False Then
        ' User pressed cancel button or X in the right corner
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If InputReturn = vbNullString Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Else
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("*" & InputReturn & "*", InputReturn), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This MOSTLY worked as is. It threw an error when I tried to clear the filter with blank input and I ended up implementing one of the solutions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226045/showalldata-method-of-worksheet-class-failed/18226225